# Pytest mock using decorator to mock function containing context manager return value not passed

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

So I am struggling with mocking this function due to the context manager.

Function under test

```
import fitz

def with_test_func(next_pdfs_path):
    text = ''
    with fitz.open(next_pdfs_path) as doc:
        text = doc
    return text
```

Test code

```
@mock.patch("content_production.fitz.open.__enter__", return_value='value_out')
def test_with_test_func(mock_fitz_open):
    assert cp.with_test_func('value_in') == 'value_out'
```

Error

```
RuntimeError: cannot open value_in: No such file or directory
```

I have tested this without the context manager and it works. So how would I fix this? thanks

**Edit**

So as suggested by @MrBean I tried this

```
@mock.patch("content_production.fitz.open.return_value.__enter__", return_value='value_out')
def test_with_test_func(mock_fitz_open):
    assert cp.with_test_func('value_in') == 'value_out'
```

It gives me this error

```
thing = <class 'fitz.fitz.Document'>, comp = 'return_value', import_path = 'content_production.fitz.open.return_value'

    def _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path):
        try:
            return getattr(thing, comp)
        except AttributeError:
>           __import__(import_path)
E           ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'content_production.fitz'; 'content_production' is not a package
```

Comment: I think you forgot a `return_value`, e.g. `content_production.fitz.open.return_value.__enter__`, to get the result of the `open` call.

Comment: Thanks I already tried that and also like this ```content_production.fitz.open.__enter__.return_value``` and they don't work. With your suggestion the error was ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'content_production.fitz'; 'content_production' is not a package```

Comment: Is `content_production` the module with your function under test, and is it top-level?

Comment: Yes top level and yes it is the module with the function. Like I say it worked without the context manager so it is something about the way the context manager works that I think is tripping me up.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was misleading - didn't notice the obvious... I put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `return_value` is a property of the mock, not of the patched function, so you cannot put it into the `patch` argument string. Instead, you have to set the return value on the mock for the `open` method:

```py
@mock.patch("content_production.fitz.open")
def test_with_test_func(mock_fitz_open):
    mock_fitz_open.return_value.__enter__.return_value = 'value_out'
    assert cp.with_test_func('value_in') == 'value_out'
```